# LU decomposition of matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

Let $A_1=L_1U_1$ and $A_2=L_2U_2$ be two matrices with their respective LU-factorizations ($L_i$ is lower triangular and $U_i$ upper triangular).

Is it possible to obtain the LU decomposition of the matrix product $A_1A_2$, exploiting the known factorizations of $A_1,A_2$?

Or is the best one can do just to compute the factorization of $A_1A_2$ from scratch?

Comment: You can write $A_1A_2=L_1(U_1L_2)U_2$, then compute the LU decomposition of $U_1L_2=L_3U_3$, and finally $AB=(L_1L_3)(U_3U_2)$. This will reduce a little the number of operations: $U_1L_2$ is roughly $n^3/6$ [FMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation) (plus lower order terms), while $L_1L_3$ and $U_3U_2$ are both roughly $n^3/6$, hence overall it's $2n^3/3$, better that $n^3$ for $A_1A_2$. But the speed also depends highly on the implementation.

Comment: Typo: $U_1L_3$ is roughly $n^3/3$, not $n^3/6$. It's less for a product of two lower-triangular (two or upper-triangular) matrices, because the result is then also triangular.